# Why is there only one SCREEN process in nested screen session?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, gnu-screen

I create `4` nested screen sessions , but there are only one `SCREEN` process:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps -ef | grep SCREEN
root      4852  4851  0 02:57 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN
root      4915  4900  0 02:58 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto SCREEN
```

Why is there only one `SCREEN` process in nested screen sessions? I think there should be `4` `SCREEN` processes:

Comment: Try `grep -i screen`?

Comment: @whjm: What is the point of using "`grep -i screen`"?

Comment: Not sure when you would see `SCREEN`. Usually what I see is just `screen`.

Comment: What do you mean by *nested screen session*?

Comment: @whjm: "nested screen sessions" means using screen command nested: input `screen` command in current terminal, and then in the new screen context, type `screen` command again, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking `screen` from within the *screen window* would not create new *screen sessions*. Instead, only new *screen windows* are created (just like <kbd>ctrl-a c</kbd>) and the new *screen windows* are running in the same *screen session*. You can verify this by pressing <kbd>ctrl-a w</kbd>. But you can force it to create new *screen sessions*, for example, with `screen -S session-name`.

A *screen window* is just a virtual terminal in which you can have a shell running. The *screen session* can be considered as the collection of all these *screen windows* running in the same screen process. The sessions can be found with `screen -ls`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! If possible, could you give a detailed analysis about `screen window` and `screen session`?

Answer (score 1):

The `screen` program creates two processes to manage the pseudo-terminal and the user's display.  One end of the pseudo-terminal is connected to the actual terminal, and the other is connected to shells which are run within `screen`.  *Any* program using pseudo-terminals (such as a terminal emulator) does this.

- `screen` (the parent process)
- `SCREEN` (the child process, which is then the parent of subsequent shells also known as "windows").

You can see this relationship by doing a "ps -ef" and looking at the `PID` and `PPID` columns.  The number shown for a given `-/bin/bash` (or whatever) in the `PPID` column will be the number shown for `SCREEN` in the `PID` column.